# Magento 2 ui component disable fields based on checkbox admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent

How can I disable some fields if a checkbox is enabled in admin panel? I'm using UI Components and Field component.

I tried something like below but it's not working.
24 hours is a checkbox, if it's selected then from_date and to_date will be disable

```
               <switcherConfig>
                    <rules>
                        <rule name="0">
                            <value>0</value>
                            <actions>
                                <action name="0">
                                    <target>from_date</target>
                                    <callback>disable</callback>
                                </action>
                                <action name="1">
                                    <target>to_date</target>
                                    <callback>disable</callback>
                                </action>
                                <action name="2">
                                    <target>24_hours</target>
                                    <callback>enable</callback>
                                </action>
                            </actions>
                        </rule>
                   
                    </rules>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </switcherConfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the below code inside your "24_hours" field's setting.

```
               <switcherConfig>
                    <rules>
                        <rule name="0">
                            <value>checked</value>
                            <actions>
                                <action name="0">
                                    <target>from_date</target>
                                    <callback>disable</callback>
                                </action>
                                <action name="1">
                                    <target>to_date</target>
                                    <callback>disable</callback>
                                </action>
                             </actions>
                        </rule>
                   
                    </rules>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </switcherConfig>
```